# NodeJS Express Function not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, geofencing

All I'm trying to do is execute geoAutocomplete in browser console so I can console log values from form. I'm getting `ReferenceError: geoAutocomplete is not defined` error.

```
const GooglePlaces = require('google-places');
const places = new GooglePlaces("myapikey");

function geoAutocomplete(input, lat, long) {
    console.log(input, lat, long);

    //const dropdown = places.autocomplete(input);
}

export default geoAutocomplete;
```

myApp.js

```
import '../sass/style.scss'
import geoAutocomplete from './modules/geoAutocomplete'

geoAutocomplete( document.querySelector('#address'), document.querySelector('#lat'), document.querySelector('#long') );
```

layout.pug

```
    script(src='/javascript/vcaApp.js' type='module')
form(method='POST' action='/addGeofence')
                    h3 Add a Geofence
                    div.input-field
                        label(for='address') Address
                        input(type='text' id='address', placeholder='Address',
                        required='true', autofocus='true' name='address')
                    div.input-field(style="display: none;")
                        input(type='number' id='lat', placeholder='Address',
                        autofocus='true' name='lat')
                    div.input-field(style="display: none;")
                        input(type='number' id='long', autofocus='true' name='long')
```

Comment: "I'm getting getAutocomplete is not defined error" — On what line? Is that the only error message reported on the console? Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @Quentin So I'm just trying to execute the function in brower console. When I paste in the function it says the function is not defined. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Editing now

Comment: @Quentin I'm almost certain its how I'm importing the modules. I am not too familiar with this idea.

Comment: Is that the only error message reported on the console? Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I believe none of my code is being executed as it is not imported properly. Tested on latest firefox and chrome. Browser is pretty much definitely not the issue

Comment: Browser is pretty much definitely the reason it doesn't work in Firefox…

Comment: `/javascript/vcaApp.js` — which file is this?

Comment: Why are you mixing `import` and `require`? Stick to one. How do you compile the code?

Comment: @Quentin vcaApp.js is myApp.js sorry.

Comment: @baao They are equivalent? OH. Not exactly sure. I am using webstorm ide.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `module.exports` / `require`. It's hard to tell where the error gets produced as you don't know how you're making the code runable in a browser (neither `require` nor `import` are supported there).

The easiest will be to just use

```
module.exports = getAutocomplete;
```

and to import the function in the other file

```
const geoAutocomplete = require('./modules/geoAutocomplete');
```

Your pre es6 compiler/transpiler/whatever will be able to handle this.

Comment: I carried this out. Seems to make more sense this way but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Then check how you are compiling the code. If you don't do that at all, the error will be that require is not defined. Just open up the browsers console @Deancoakley